# заголовки в GtkTreeView

Tags: c, gtk

Здравствуйте!
Необходимо создать таблицу в GtkTreeView с заголовком столбцов вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я использовал **gtk_tree_view_column_set_widget** для добавления нескольких GtkWidget в заголовок, однако, это не позволяет реализовать данную задачу.

Comment: o_O С каких это пор Gtk.TreeView нужен для таблиц? Я думал, он для древовидных структур нужен (как в ФМ)

Comment: GtkTreeView - виджет для отображения и деревьев и списков(таблиц)